# Get last value in table depending on column values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that has 3 columns

```
id, Name, time
```

id is an incrementing int value
Name is a string identifier
time is just a epoc value of when the item was added to the table.

I can have something that looks like this.

```
1, Jeff, 1520288589
2, Jeff, 1520288590
3, Jeff, 1520288591
4, Tim, 1520288592
5, Jeff, 1520288593
```

I would like to know how I can create an SQL statement to request the last Tim row and the last Jeff row.

Comment: Hi there. There's no need to add "any help appreciated" and similar material to your questions - it gets [edited out anyway](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions), so it'd save some editors some time if it was not added in the first place! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you can just do:

```
select max(id), name, max(time)
from t
group by name;
```

The `id` and `time` seem to both be incrementing over time.

A more general solution is:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.time = (select max(t2.time) from t t2 where t2.name = t.name);
```